# How to make dpkg manage python3.6?

Tags: dpkg

python3.6 was installed this way.

```
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.0/Python-3.6.0.tar.xz
tar -xf Python-3.6.0.tar.xz
cd ./Python-3.6.0
sudo ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/python3.6 --with-ensurepip=install --enable-ipv6
sudo make
sudo make install
sudo ln -s /usr/local/python3.6/bin/python3.6 /usr/bin/python3.6
sudo ln -s /usr/local/python3.6/bin/pip3.6 /usr/bin/pip3.6
```

python3.6 can't be listed by dpkg after installation.

```
dpkg -l |grep python3.6
```

or

```
dpkg -l |grep python3* |grep 3.6
```

Nothing output.
Python3.6 can't be listed by dpkg,does it mean that python3.6 can't be managed by dpkg - package manager for Debian?
How to make it managed by dpkg?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dpkg` only manages packages, it doesn't know about software installed in other ways.

There are different approaches you can use. You can use [`checkinstall`](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/checkinstall) to create a package from the results of `make install`. Alternatively, you can rebuild the Debian [`python3.6`](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/python3.6).

It's important to realise though that the system Python package is intended for the system's use. To develop with newer versions of Python, you should use virtual environments, without attempting to replace the system's Python packages...